# python not displaying executable output properly

Tags: python, linux, shell, subprocess, executable

I am using code to execute an executable file via python in Linux Terminal.

The code I use in python is

```py
import subprocess


def executable_shell():
    # to run cosmo file     
    x=subprocess.run('cd .. && cd build &&  ./COSMO', shell=True, capture_output=True)
    print(x)

executable_shell()
```

Here COSMO is my executable file
To run this python file I use command: `$ python3 file.py`

The code is working but the display file is without line space between them, like each new line is starting on the same line rather than jumping to a new line.

But if I run this executable in the normal way from the terminal

```
$ ./COSMO
```

I am getting the correct format.

Example output:

```
xxxxx xxxxx xx
```

Desired output:

```
xxxxx
xxxxx
xx
```

Comment: Use `text=True` in options, and then access `x.stdout` to get the stream of bytes in return. `x` is not the output, it is an object that encapsulate the process management.

Comment: This could be an end of line conversion problem. To make sure, you should redirect the output of the COSMO executable to a file, and examine the content of the file with an hexadecimal editor (or just dump the content in hexa with a tiny Python script).

Comment: Not sure what COSMO bin does but try add to your print statement `print("{}\r".format(x))` . Keep in mind that `subprocess.run()` returns a CompletedProcess instance aka a process that has finished when `capture_output` is `true` stdout and stderr will be captured

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you are running would print a human-readable representation of a `CompletedProcess` object which includes, but contains much more than, the actual output from your subprocess, on a single line.

```
Python 3.7.2 (default, Mar 25 2020, 10:15:53) 
[Clang 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.29)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import subprocess
>>> x = subprocess.run(['printf', '%s\n', 'foo', 'bar', 'baz'], capture_output=True)
>>> print(x)
CompletedProcess(args=['printf', '%s\n', 'foo', 'bar', 'baz'], returncode=0, stdout=b'foo\nbar\nbaz\n', stderr=b'')
```

To actually print only the output, try

```
>>> print(x.stdout.decode())
foo
bar
baz
```

Better yet, have Python decode it for you.

```py
import subprocess


def executable_shell():
    # to run cosmo file     
    x = subprocess.run(
        # Just the command, as a list of arguments, so we can avoid shell=True
        ['./COSMO'],
        # Specify which directory to run it in
        cwd='../build',
        # Throw an exception if the command fails (optional but recommended)
        check=True,
        # Have Python decode the output as text instead of raw bytes
        text=True,
        # Capture output, as before
        capture_output=True)
    return x.stdout

print(executable_shell())
```

Notice how I added `text=True` (and also refactored to use `check=True` and get rid of `shell=True`) and how the function now returns the result, and the caller prints it (or does something else with it, as the case may be).  Generally, you want functions to return results rather than print them; this makes it easier to reuse them for other tasks.