# Python subprocess module returncode issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, kubernetes, subprocess, kubectl

I am using a python subprocess module to execute **kubectl exec command**, the command is returning an error. Still I am getting a returncode of 0 and pod status of CRASHLOOPBACK state which is not valid.

Need help on fetching the correct returncode on execution of command.
Executed command:

```py
cmd = f"kubectl -n {cls.NS} exec -i {mainpod} -- sh -c \"/opt/user/data/bin/mdm -waitDb -v && /opt/user/data/bin/mdm -applySchema /etc/data/db/tables/ -v\""
result = subprocess.run(shlex.split(cmd))
```

Log output:

```
INFO : Connection Obtained - database ready
ERROR: /etc/data/db/tables/ is not a valid directory
INFO : Closed DB connection.

CompletedProcess(args=['kubectl', '-n', 'test', 'exec', '-i', 'db-pod', '--', 'sh', '-c', '/opt/user/data/bin/mdm -waitDb -v && /opt/user/data/bin/mdm -applySchema /etc/data/db/tables/ -v'], returncode=0)
```

How can I fetch the correct returncode in the above case?

Comment: Your Python code looks fine. It appears that the problem is that `kubectl` does not relay back the status code from `sh -c` correctly.  See also https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/26424

Comment: As an aside, pasting things into a string only so you can then `shlex.split()` it immediately seems like extra work. Try `cmd = ["kubectl", "-n", cls.NS, "exec", "-i", mainpod, "--", "sh", "-c", "/opt/user/data/bin/mdm -waitDb -v && /opt/user/data/bin/mdm -applySchema /etc/data/db/tables/ -v"]` (maybe add `str()` if your variables are not strings).

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66220772/python-not-displaying-executable-output-properly is for proper output receiving.
My scenario is that when I receive an error log, i need the exact return code other than zero which is not working.

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't see what you were asking at first because of formatting problems; sorry for the spurious link.

Comment: @tripleee what else can i try out to fetch the status, as i need to execute kubectl command using python, any idea ?

Comment: Again, the Python side looks fine. The question is how to get `kubectl` to actually report the correct status code. I'm not familiar enough with that tool to tell you what to change, though the linked bug report offers some promising discussions.

Comment: That link uses kubectl run to create a new pod, but in my case i need to work on already created pod. Additionally, what is needed is to get the return code for the command executed inside, which as per my logs is in error state, but the returncode is not valid.

Comment: Does `mdm` actually set the correct exit code?

Comment: If i execute ``` "kubectl", "-n", cls.NS, "exec", "-i", mainpod, "--", "sh", "-c", "/opt/user/data/bin/mdm -waitDb -v ``` command, i receive a correct return code, its when i execute the second half of command, i receive an error with the incorrect returncode.
which is visible in logs: 
```
ERROR: /etc/data/db/tables/ is not a valid directory 
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. Does `mdm` return a non-zero exit code when there is an error when you execute it outside of `kubectl`?

Comment: it needs to be with kubectl as that program executes inside a container within  a pod, so externally cannot be tested.

Comment: But if the command doesn't return a non-zero exit code, the problem is not in `kubectl` either.

Comment: But what happens is that the error logs are visible, and the pod status remains in CRASHLOOPBACK state dur to failed process and still the return code remains 0.
Because of which it won't be possible to commute whether the process failed or completed.